# how do I create web service through mongolab rest api for basic database operation using curl in php?

Tags: php, curl, mlab

I am new to mongodb and mongolab.
Any one can tell me how to access mongolab database through curl in php,not through ajax.
I want to create api like LOGIN, RESET_PASSWORD, RESIGTRATION.
How do I create above web service.

I have reffered https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-REST-API-for-MongoDB for documentation.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a PHP-enabled server I'd recommend using the [MongoDB PHP driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/) to connect. The MongoLab REST API is really intended for use in applications that otherwise wouldn't need an server.

Comment: I don't want to use [MongoDB PHP driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/) I want to use access mongolab database through mongolab rest api in php using curl